# jQuery Toggle -- One Function One Click Then Another

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

Here's what I would like to do in pseudocode form.

```
Bind Two Functions to Click Event

On 1st/Odd Clicks Do FunctionA()

On 2nd/Even Clicks Do FunctionB()
```

The .toggle() function seems to not be designed for this.

I'm sure this exists in jQuery but my googling hasn't resulted in anything. :)

Comment: Odd and Even from a table rows/list items?

Comment: Thanks everyone! :D I just assumed toggle hid elements. :">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see how this isn't *exactly* what [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) is designed for...

```
$('#someEl').toggle(FunctionA, FunctionB);
```

You may be confused by the *other* [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) function that exists in jQuery, which won't be called if you pass functions as the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
var i=1;
$(".a").click (function () {if (i%2!=0) FunctionA();i++;});
$(".a").click (function () {if (i%2==0) FunctionB();i++;});
```

Comment: Just to save precious CPU cycles: var flag=true; $(".a").click (function () {if (flag) FunctionB();flag=!flag;}); $(".a").click (function () {if (!flag) FunctionB();flag=!flag;});

Answer (score 0):

You just need to ask Google the right question ;)

```
$(selector).toggle(function(),function(),function(),...)
```

- function()   Required. Specifies a function to run every EVEN time the
  element is clicked
- function()   Required. Specifies a function to run    every ODD time
  the element is clicked
- function(),...   Optional.    Specifies additional functions to toggle
  between

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

Comment: The information in the body of this answer is right, but the link is not helpful. That's for effect toggle not event toggle.

Comment: That's where I copied/pasted from. Scroll down and you'll see "Toggle Between Functions" It doesn't talk about the effect anymore. I just showed you my source

Comment: My apologies! It's there after all. *sheepish*